# Threading memory leaks even closing the thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, ram

My last  question was about the same program I'm doing, in this case, the problem is that I use threading to do a ping in some devices conected in LAN.
The program should use less than 80 MB but after 5 hours the usage is more than 3 GB, I was searching in python Bug tracker but all the information and that's a coommon report of users, but the solutions that gives me doesn't fell very confident.
Even I tried to get the location data of threads to delete, but I didn't find any option to do it, I supose that is because pyhton you can't access.

This is the code:

```py
def update_ping(self, data, ping_queue):
        result_queue = queue.Queue()
        local = threading.local()
        while not self.stop_threads:
            threads = []
            for seccion in data:
                lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                for linea in lineas:
                    equipos = linea["equipos"]
                    for equipo in equipos:
                        ip = equipo["ip"]
                        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.analyze_device, args=(ip, result_queue), daemon=False)
                        threads.append(thread)
                        thread.start()
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
            new_data = []
            print(f"Tamaño cola:{result_queue.qsize()}")
            while not result_queue.empty():
                ip, status_color = result_queue.get()
                for seccion in data:
                    lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                    for linea in lineas:
                        equipos = linea["equipos"]
                        for equipo in equipos:
                            if equipo["ip"] == ip:
                                equipo["status_color"] = status_color
            for seccion in data:
                nuevos_equipos_seccion = []
                lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                for linea in lineas:
                    nuevos_equipos_linea = []
                    equipos = linea["equipos"]
                    for equipo in equipos:
                        ip = equipo["ip"]
                        status_color = equipo["status_color"]
                        nuevos_equipos_linea.append(equipo)
                    linea["equipos"] = nuevos_equipos_linea
                    nuevos_equipos_seccion.append(linea)
                seccion["lineas"] = nuevos_equipos_seccion
                new_data.append(seccion)
            ping_queue.put(new_data)
            print("Ping realizado")
            print(f"Recolección: {gc.collect()}")
            print(f"Depuradores: {gc.get_debug()}")
            print(f"Basura: {gc.garbage}")


    def analyze_device(self, ip, result_queue):
        try:
            if self.check_online(ip):
                status_color = "green"
            else:
                status_color = "red"
            
            result_queue.put((ip, status_color))
            return
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error en el hilo {ip}: {str(e)}")
    
    def check_online(self, ip):
        check = False
        for _ in range(5):
            data = ping(ip)
            if isinstance(data, float):
                check = True
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(0.5)
        return check
```

Know how can make the program delete the garbage data or detect for release some memory. Or an alternative form that use paralelism without this problem about memory, the paralelism is necessary because the function verfy the lan connection about 200 devices

Comment: Not an answer, but what is the purpose of the `time.sleep(0.5)` call in `check_online`? it causes the thread to live for an extra half second if the given `ip` does not respond to a ping, but otherwise it does nothing. In particular, it does _not_ slow down the rate at which `update_ping` function creates _other_ threads to ping other `ip`s.

Comment: Yes you are right, I put it because I was testing, there are not reason keep that line

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** How many threads does a typical call to `update_ping(...)` create? and

**Q:** What does "the usage" mean?

Your program creates a new thread for every `analyze_device(...)` call, and it potentially creates a huge number of those threads all at once. Each of those threads needs a significant chunk of virtual memory for its stack, and even if the program doesn't need a huge amount of *real* memory, it might never give its *virtual* allocation back to the OS.

Three gigabytes of virtual memory is not, in and of itself, a problem—especially not if the virtual memory is mostly unused—but a better solution might be to make the `analyze_device(...)` calls through a [*thread pool*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) that uses only some controlled number of *worker threads* to do the work.

See also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of these program is to monitoring 24/7, when the treads are active are nearly 192, when are working are using 15MB of memory RAM more than the program uses that when the threads are not active, but when they finish the memory that use should come back to normal levels, releasing the memory used by threads, but doesn't happen, because for some reason the program don't detect all the data used or don't detect that is a old data that shoud be removed, that makes that Ram usage increases 4-5 MB per cicle, if the program have to be monitoring 24/7, will use the entire RAM.

Comment: Also I check that these could hapen with other libraries but i will try to aplicate the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Working in the program I realise that you can use a subprocess to do the threading task and return the data to the main program, doing that, when the second task finishes all the memory that you use will released even the memory. In my case, I used this function in the main code:

```
data_str = subprocess.check_output(args, universal_newlines=True)
```

And to get the data in the second program:

```
recived_data = sys.argv[1:]
```

In this using libraries **subprocess** and **sys**.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using a thread pool there, instead of creating a thread for each device. Even creating one thread for each device, an dkeeping it alive, if you have 200, should be fine.

The problem is that you re-create new threads in  a massive scale, at each iteration. Using subprocessing instead of threading there may have resolved for you, but just because the OS cleans up after each subprocess - however, the overhead for each "ping" is enormous, as a subprocess is "massive" in terms of system resources used, as compared to threads.

Using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` will create an easy to use Pool, and you can easily put in 100 or even 300 workers so that all your stuff is done in parallel (the default is  2 X the number of CPU cores):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import queue
import threading

...

def update_ping(self, data, ping_queue):
    result_queue = queue.Queue()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(300) as executor:
        while not self.stop_threads:
            futures = []
            for seccion in data:
                lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                for linea in lineas:
                    equipos = linea["equipos"]
                    for equipo in equipos:
                        ip = equipo["ip"]
                        futures.append(executor.submit(self.analyze_device, ip, result_queue))
                                        
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                # This for is just to emulate your previous code: ensuring
                # all tasks are executed before proceeding to next batch
                # you can do away with it, if it is not needed.
                # also, you could fetch return values from the target function
                # here, and not need the queue.
                pass
            new_data = []
            print(f"Tamaño cola:{result_queue.qsize()}")
            while not result_queue.empty():
                ip, status_color = result_queue.get()
                for seccion in data:
                    lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                    for linea in lineas:
                        equipos = linea["equipos"]
                        for equipo in equipos:
                            if equipo["ip"] == ip:
                                equipo["status_color"] = status_color
            for seccion in data:
                nuevos_equipos_seccion = []
                lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                for linea in lineas:
                    nuevos_equipos_linea = []
                    equipos = linea["equipos"]
                    for equipo in equipos:
                        ip = equipo["ip"]
                        status_color = equipo["status_color"]
                        nuevos_equipos_linea.append(equipo)
                    linea["equipos"] = nuevos_equipos_linea
                    nuevos_equipos_seccion.append(linea)
                seccion["lineas"] = nuevos_equipos_seccion
                new_data.append(seccion)
            ping_queue.put(new_data)
            print("Ping realizado")
            print(f"Recolección: {gc.collect()}")
            print(f"Depuradores: {gc.get_debug()}")
            print(f"Basura: {gc.garbage}")


    ...
```

Note that this removes any need to start a new thread, and remove it for each device - just the function call remains, which is wrapped in a "Future".

There is a chance the passing of the Queue to thousands of threads to be what was leaking in your original implementation - and a smaller chance of it still leak here, though I doubt it . In any case, check the docs for `concurrent.futures` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html